# Should I keep @angular/compiler in dependencies or devDependencies?

Tags: angular

Should I keep @angular/compiler in dependencies or devDependencies in package.json? Why do I need it in dependencies if my production code is already compiled?

Answer (score 9):

*package.json* is organized into two groups of packages:

- **Dependencies** are essential to running applications.
- **DevDependencies** are only necessary to develop applications.

You should keep *@angular/compiler* in dependencies because as it mention in its official document as below

> Angular's template compiler. It understands templates and can convert them to code that makes the application run and render. Typically you don’t interact with the compiler directly; rather, you use it indirectly via platform-browser-dynamic when JIT compiling in the browser. For more information, see the Ahead-of-time Compilation guide.

For more detail you can check its [official document](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages).

Comment: "@angular/cli" is not referenced in the documentation, and "@angular/compiler" is only required "dependencies" in JIT mode (which is not recommended, why I referenced AOT)...

Answer (score 5):

2021 UPDATE:

The AOT compiler has improved significantly, and can be used for development.

- The "@angular/compiler" and "@angular/cli" references can be moved to devDependencies
- You can use the "BrowserModule", instead of "PlatformBrowserDynamic" which was used for JIT compilation.

Answer (score -3):

**Please have look on below --**

If you look at your package.json file it will contain two types of dependencies

**1. dependencies:** 
   The "dependencies":{} will contain all your packages which angular application required to run.
 **2. devDependencies:**
   The "devDependencies":{} will contain all the packages which is required at the time of development of the angular application.

Now coming to the point you don't need to any dependencies if your application is deployed in the production.
You will only need dependencies related to the node and other thing.
Here is the link of angular official documentation refer it for more detail 
  https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all